# Install and Configure Nginx/Lighttpd with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nginx, lighttpd

I was trying to test my sample application's performance on Nginx and Lighttpd local web servers.

I have successfully installed both the servers on my mac machine (Mac Lion). But I am facing issues in configuring NodeJS app with both servers.